# Merge elements of two inner maps into a single one in terraform

Tags: terraform

I create a map as follows

```
locals {
  ns_per_project = merge({
    for proj, projvalue in local.projects:
    proj => {
      for key,value in data.kubernetes_namespace.ns: 
        key=>{
          clusterId = rancher2_cluster.cluster.id
          projectId = lookup(value.metadata[0].annotations, "field.cattle.io/projectId", null)
          projectName = proj
        }
      if (lookup(value.metadata[0].annotations, "field.cattle.io/projectId", null)) == rancher2_project.pr["${proj}"].id
    }
  })
}
```

The result I get is

```
ns_per_project = {
  default = {
    default = {
      clusterId   = "local"
      projectId   = "local:p-xxxx"
      projectName = "default"
    }
  }
  system  = {
    cattle-dashboards                          = {
      clusterId   = "local"
      projectId   = "local:p-xxxxx"
      projectName = "system"
    }
    cattle-fleet-clusters-system               = {
      clusterId   = "local"
      projectId   = "local:p-xxxxx"
      projectName = "system"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is my **expected output**, basically a single map containing all elements of both "sub-maps"

```
ns_per_project = {
  default = {
    clusterId   = "local"
    projectId   = "local:p-xxxx"
    projectName = "default"
  }
  cattle-dashboards                          = {
    clusterId   = "local"
    projectId   = "local:p-xxxxx"
    projectName = "system"
  }
  cattle-fleet-clusters-system               = {
    clusterId   = "local"
    projectId   = "local:p-xxxxx"
    projectName = "system"
  }
}
```

I am not sure if and how I can achieve this. While the `merge` in my original locals does not work, I also tried this

```
locals = {
  merged = [
    for proj,projvalue in local.ns_per_project: merge({
      for key,value in projvalue: key => value
    })
  ]
}
```

Which also is **not** the expected result

```
merged = [
  {
    default = {
      clusterId   = "local"
      projectId   = "local:p-xxxx"
      projectName = "default"
    }
  },
  {
    cattle-dashboards                          = {
      clusterId   = "local"
      projectId   = "local:p-xxxx"
      projectName = "system"
    }
    cattle-fleet-clusters-system               = {
      clusterId   = "local"
      projectId   = "local:p-xxxxx"
      projectName = "system"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution following [this post](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-combine-all-tuples-in-list-of-maps/32543/2)

```
locals {
  ns_per_project = merge([
    for proj, projvalue in local.projects: {
        for key,value in data.kubernetes_namespace.ns: 
          key => {
            clusterId = rancher2_cluster.cluster.id
            projectId = lookup(value.metadata[0].annotations, "field.cattle.io/projectId", null)
            projectName = proj
          }
        if (lookup(value.metadata[0].annotations, "field.cattle.io/projectId", null)) == rancher2_project.pr["${proj}"].id
    }
  ]...)
```

The key point is to use `...` symbol to enable [Expanding Function Arguments](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments)